# Java JFrame render lagging

Tags: java, swing, jframe, lag

I'm trying to make a simple game in java using the swing engine. However currently I am having issues with lag. This simple code draws a circle and moves it from the top left corner of the frame to the bottom right corner, but it lags a lot. While my pc is somewhat old, i3 4gb ram, I think it should manage to perform this without lag?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

  public Timer timer;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;

  public Game() {
    timer = new Timer(20, this);
    timer.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    x++;
    y++;
    repaint();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    Game game = new Game();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lag" ? What is lagging ? There is a delay of 20 milliseconds in `new Timer(20, this);`

Comment: You should consider using `paintComponent` over `paint`. Also try reducing the delay from 20 to 10 or even 5 milliseconds